# Release-Plan and Release-Planning tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

### Swapping and Merging Release Plan(ning) Synonyms

We currently have the following unmerged synonyms:

- [release-plan](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release-plan)
- [release-planning](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release-planning)

I'm fine with them being synonyms, although arguably one is an activity that produces an artifact. However, currently `release-planning -> release-plan`, so the activity is a synonym for the artifact. I think it might make more sense the other way around and wanted some feedback about that.

Secondly, once we decide which should be the synonym, I'd like to merge the tags unless we want to de-synonymize them. Any objections to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skimming through the tagged posts I'd assume both are being used interchangeably.

Besides, assuming that most of the community is not concerned about the differentiation between the activity and the artifact, I'd agree with the tag merge.

Comment: I've swapped it to `release plan -> release planning` and merged the tags. I'm accepting this as the answer.